# Variadic template deduction from multiple template class parameter

Tags: c++, c++17

I've searched this topic and the possible solutions for a while, but non of the answer is achieving what I wish to do.

That's I have some class template like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Entry {
public:
    Entry(const std::string &key, const T &value) {}    
};

class Dictionary {
public:
    template <typename... ValueTs>
    explicit Dictionary(Entry<ValueTs> &&... key_value_pairs) {}
};
```

In my main function, I am able to declare a Dictionary class using this method (using clang-10 -std=c++17)

```
int main() {
    Dictionary main_dict {
        Entry {"TestKeyword", 123},
        Entry {"testKeyword2", 234.5f},
    };

  return 0;
}
```

But what I wish to do is to eliminate the `Entry` keyword within the main_dict variable and achieving something like this (Not able to compile):

```
int main() {
    Dictionary main_dict {
        {"TestKeyword", 123},
        {"testKeyword2", 234.5f},
    };

  return 0;
}
```

My assumption for doing this is that I specifically declare `Entry` in `Dictionary`'s constructor to wrap all types, and therefore only `Entry` template can be the parameter type.

I am wondering if this work around is possible or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it's possible because of the way the language parses the brace init expression. The only way I can see is to make your constructor take an initializer list. That has other implication though.

Comment: *aggregate initialization* of `struct` can not work with type deduction. and the only way to do a similar thing is `std::initializer_list<T>` or `T (&&)[N]`, but their elements need to have the same type. finally I think you can declare as `template<typename... Args>Dictionary(Args&&...)` with SFINAE and then use `Dictionary{ "key1", 123, "key2", 456.78 }`.